# Unmounting removable drive in AIR 2 beta

Tags: macos, air, beta

I ran into a huge problem with my AIR project today (I'm using new AIR 2 beta SDK). Is it possible at all to unmount a flash drive from inside the AIR app on Mac OS X? I can't find any solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Use NativeProcess class to run diskutil unmount Unix command.